# Should I go with ajax call or assign map of state and its corresponding cities to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a map of State and its related list of cities.
So from UI whenever user change State in dropdown it should populate it's corresponding list of cities in other dropdown.

I was thinking of two approaches:

1. Ajax call each time state changes to get List of city.
2. Get the  map of state and list of city and assign it to a javascript
   variable in jsp page.

In both approaches, I will query database only once during class instantiation and get the state and list of city and assign it to a property from the class.

Can someone suggest which one is better?

Comment: In the first case you will query database more than once

Comment: It depends on the amount of data. If it's not that much data, I would load all at once and store it in an object.

Comment: No I will query database only once when my java class is instantiated and during ajax calls I will get the list of city from the java class's property. So in my java file I have created a property as a Map of String and List of city.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how important page load time is, if you want the page to load really quickly then use the ajax approach. Also if the amount of cities is large its probably best to go with ajax.

If load time is not a concern and there isn't much data then assign it to javascript variable through jsp.